# Why would a fake feature with random numbers get selected in feature importance?

Tags: scikit-learn, feature-selection, random-forest, feature-engineering

I'm using a `sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100)` to work on this challenge:
https://kaggle.com/c/two-sigma-financial-news

I've plotted my feature importance:

[image]

I created a fake feature called `random` which is just numbers pulled from `np.random.randn()`. Unfortunately, it seems to have quite significant feature importance.

**How am I supposed to interpret this?** I had expected it to be at the bottom.

PS xgboost seems to discard this feature, as it should.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scikit-learn's random forest [feature importance is based on mean decrease in impurity](https://explained.ai/rf-importance/index.html), which is fast to compute and faithful to the original creation of the Random Forest method. In short, the default `feature_importances_` gives a numerical justification of the Random Forest's representation of the feature importance using its *native metric of construction*. Like you saw, this metric has the drawback that it can say noise is an important feature. So you may want to consider other feature importance methods, like permutation feature importance, which will give you a more apples-to-apples comparison with other models you will test. There are pros and cons to many of these methods so be aware of them.

Comment: Can you give an example of a "con" to using permutation importances?